# Prove that if through three given points two planes can be drawn, then infinitely many planes throught these points can be drawn.

Tags: geometry, 3d

Prove that if through three given points two planes can be drawn, then infinitely many planes through these points can be drawn. I don't get how this is possible, since there is unique plane passing through three point, how would I get two planes?

Comment: It is not always unique $$\cdots$$

Comment: Would you provide some more information?

Comment: I am claiming that there exist configurations of three points with more than one plane passing through them. One way to find such a set: Take the intersection of two planes, and pick three points in that intersection. (Also, the $\cdots$ *was* a hint!)

Comment: construct a plan aboviously passing through the $3$ points, and find what can make this plane unique or not

Comment: But if the three points lie in one line, then there are infinity number of planes passing through it(this is easy to prove). However is it possible to prove this statement if the three points don't lie in one line?

Comment: If two planes are distinct, and they intersect, then their intersection must be a single $X$ (what?).  Then the three points must be in the same $X$.  What does that say about other planes that might contain those three points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the three points be denoted $P,Q,R$. We wish to prove the following implication:

- If two planes exist containing $P,Q,R$, then infinitely many planes exist containing $P,Q,R$.

Let's break the proof into two cases.

Case 1: $P,Q,R$ are co-linear. Then the implication is true because its conclusion is true: infinitely many planes exist containing $P,Q,R$.

Case 2: $P,Q,R$ are not co-linear. Then the implication is true because its hypothesis is false: only one plane exists through $P,Q,R$.

Comment: how can you prove infinitely many planes contain 3 collinear points?

Answer (score 2):

Beware the hidden assumption."There is a unique plane passing through 3 points." This is only true if the 3 points are not co-linear. Don't assume the points are NOT co-linear. If 2 planes intersect, their intersection is a line, and there are infinitely planes containing that line. So if 3 points are co-linear, there are infinitely many planes through the line that contains the 3 points.